# trouble with switching the stack frame

Tags: gcc, assembly, c++14, setjmp

Why does the following code crash under Windows 10? It gets stuck in `yield()` in the `setjmp()` call. What rules did I violate? I think I never return from functions where `setjmp()` is called. The code works perfectly under linux/amd64.

```
class coroutine
{
  jmp_buf env_in_;
  jmp_buf env_out_;

  ::std::function<void()> f_;

  bool running_;
  bool terminated_;

  ::std::unique_ptr<char[]> stack_;

  char* const stack_top_;

public:
  explicit coroutine(::std::size_t const N = 128 * 1024) :
    running_{false},
    terminated_{true},
    stack_(new char[N]),
    stack_top_(stack_.get() + N)
  {
  }

  template <typename F>
  explicit coroutine(::std::size_t const N, F&& f) :
    coroutine(N)
  {
    assign(::std::forward<F>(f));
  }

  auto terminated() const noexcept
  {
    return terminated_;
  }

  template <typename F>
  void assign(F&& f)
  {
    running_ = terminated_ = false;

    f_ = [this, f = ::std::forward<F>(f)]() mutable 
      {
        // stack switch
#if defined(__amd64__) || defined(__amd64) || defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__x86_64)
        asm volatile(
          "movq %%rsp, %0"
          :
          : "rm" (stack_top_)
          : "rsp"
        );
#elif defined(i386) || defined(__i386) || defined(__i386__)
        asm volatile(
          "movl %%esp, %0"
          :
          : "rm" (stack_top_)
          : "esp"
        );
#else
#error "can't switch stack frame"
#endif

        f(*this);

        running_ = false;

        terminated_ = true;

        yield();
      };
  }

  void yield() noexcept
  {
    if (setjmp(env_out_))
    {
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      longjmp(env_in_, 1);
    }
  }

  void resume() noexcept
  {
    if (setjmp(env_in_))
    {
      return;
    }
    else if (running_)
    {
      longjmp(env_out_, 1);
    }
    else
    {
      running_ = true;

      f_();
    }
  }
};
```

Here is the test program:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "coroutine.hpp"

struct A
{
  ~A()
  {
    ::std::cout << "destroyed" << ::std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  coroutine c(1024 * 1024);

  c.assign([](coroutine& c)
    {
      A a;

      for (int i{}; i != 3; ++i)
      {
        ::std::cout << i << ::std::endl;

        c.yield();
      }
    }
  );

  while (!c.terminated())
  {
    c.resume();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: At&t syntax has operands reversed so you are not actually switching stack, rather, you are saving the stack pointer. This probably doesn't cause the fault though. I don't think adding the stack pointer to the clobber makes sense either, as that might instruct the compiler to save and restore it, negating your switch (even if you do it in the correct direction). Also note that `new char[]` might not align your stack properly.

Comment: @Jester Your point was correct, but the problem persists. Can I change the question? Doesn't new return a pointer aligned to fit every alignment?

Comment: @Jester Clobbering the stack pointer has no effect (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52813).  OTOH, switching contexts does raise the question about all the other registers.  Perhaps they should all be clobbered instead (along with memory and flags).

Comment: Exactly, that's was the problem. The other registers weren't restored. A custom setjmp/longjmp solved it.